# Apps Script For within For Faster

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I used the below code to get the data from API.
I used for loop within for loop and it's taking long time and program stops as time exceeds.

```
function devicedetails(){
var apikey='YWQ0OWFhYjgtNTY2asiHSNSajiasn'
var todaydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")
var thirtydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24*30), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")
var cisss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var workspacesheet = cisss.getSheetByName("Device");
var lastRows = workspacesheet.getLastRow()+1;

for(var im = 2; im < lastRows; im++)
    {      
      var workspacedata = workspacesheet.getRange('B'+im).getValue();
      var encodedata = encodeURIComponent(workspacedata);
      var cisurl = "https://testapi.com/v1/workspaceDurationMetrics?workspaceId="+encodedata+"&aggregation=daily&measurement=timeUsed&from="+thirtydate+"T00%3A00%3A00.00Z&to="+todaydate+"T00%3A00%3A00.00Z";
    var cisss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var ciswsLocation = cisss.getSheetByName("HourlyUsed")
    var lastRow = ciswsLocation.getLastRow();

    var headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${apikey} `
    };

    var options = {
        "method" : "get",
        "headers" : headers 
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cisurl,options);
    var cisjson=response.getContentText();
    var cisdata=JSON.parse(cisjson);
       
    
    for(var i = 0; i < cisdata['items'].length; i++)
    {
       ciswsLocation.getRange(lastRow+1+i,1).setValue([cisdata["workspaceId"]]);
      ciswsLocation.getRange(lastRow+1+i,2).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date([cisdata["items"][i]['start']]), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd"));
      ciswsLocation.getRange(lastRow+1+i,3).setValue([cisdata["items"][i]['duration']]);
    }      
}
}
```

Please help me how to reduce time of execution?

Comment: if you have multiple requests, considering using UrlfetchApp.fetchAll .  Move fetchapp service out of the loop. So does the set valaue function. You can use a list(array) to store the data fetched from response and parse them to the spreadsheet all at time. I believe this would save you lot of time and it's actually the best practice by document.

Comment: The main problem I am seeing in your code is that you are using `setValue` inside a for loop in addition to the one mentioned by liquidkat. I strongly recommend you review [batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations) basically, you need to relegate the operations that add to the sheet to the minimum possible and use [`setValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what liqidkat said.

With that, it may look something like this:

```
function devicedetails() {

  /** Variables **/
  const apikey ='YWQ0OWFhYjgtNTY2asiHSNSajiasn'

  const todaydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  const thirtydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24*30), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")

  /** Sheet Variables **/
  const cisss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()

  const workspacesheet = cisss.getSheetByName("Device")
  const workspaceData = workspacesheet.getRange(2, 2, workspacesheet.getLastRow()-1).getValues().flat()

  const ciswsLocation = cisss.getSheetByName("HourlyUsed")
  const lastRow = ciswsLocation.getLastRow()

  /** Request Handling **/
  const allRequests = workspaceData.map(i => {

    const encodeData = encodeURIComponent(i)
    return {
      "url": `https://testapi.com/v1/workspaceDurationMetrics?workspaceId=${encodeData}&aggregation=daily&measurement=timeUsed&from=${thirtydate}T00%3A00%3A00.00Z&to=${todaydate}T00%3A00%3A00.00Z`,
      "method": "get",
      "headers": {
          "Content-type": "application/json",
          "Authorization": `Bearer ${apikey}`
      }
    }
  
  })

  /** Response Handling **/
  const allResponses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(allRequests)

  const data = allResponses.map(response => {

    const cisjson = response.getContentText()
    const cisData = JSON.parse(cisjson)
    return cisData[`items`].map(i => [
                                       cisdata["workspaceId"], 
                                       Utilities.formatDate(new Date(i['start']), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd"),
                                       i['duration']
                                     ])

  })

  /** Set data **/
  ciswsLocation.getRange(lastRow+1, 3, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data)
  
}
```

See Also:

- [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [UrlFetchApp.fetchAll()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))
- [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: I am getting, Exception: Bad value in the line `const allResponses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(allRequests)`

when I log `allRequests` , I am getting all the correct link with headers.
But don't know why I am getting this error

Comment: @Moses01 Updated. I had written the requests to be formatted into an array of arrays, when they should've been an array of objects. Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Still I am getting error in the same line but with different error
Exception: Request failed for https://testapi.com returned code 502. Truncated server response: {"message":"Couldn't reach time series database","errors":[{"description":"Couldn't reach time series database"}],"trackingId":"ROUTER1-3... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)

Comment: Does testapi.com even exist?

Comment: It's a private website, So it cannot be accessed in public. I was using the same code which I mentioned in the question, it is working fine, In the code you gave, before the line `const allResponses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(allRequests)` I logged and I get all the url with the device list, but in the line  `const allResponses = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(allRequests)` I am getting the error ;( I have a doubt, is `url` variable is allowed in the API?
Please help me on this to work

Comment: I went through `UrlFetchApp` document from Google, I found `fetchAll(allRequests)` will accept list but the code you provided is returning `allRequests` as dictionary. Can you please help to return `allRequests` as List instead Dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

I took the liberty of editing your script to replace all getValue/setValue with getValues/setValues.  And I moved all variable that only need to be set once outside the loop.  First I get all workspacedata, then in side the loop, index into that array for each row.  Next since your results are contiguous in rows and columns, I collect all the results and make one call to setValues to place in the sheet.

Although I am not able to test it since input data is not available I believe it will work and will run much faster.

Although Google has made improvements in it performance of getValue/setValue by caching requests I try to organize my spreadsheets so that I will always use getValues/setValues.  Same for other getters and setters.

**Script**

```
function devicedetails(){
  var apikey='YWQ0OWFhYjgtNTY2asiHSNSajiasn'
  var todaydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var thirtydate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(Date.now() - 1000*60*60*24*30), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var cisss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var workspacesheet = cisss.getSheetByName("Device");

  var lastRows = workspacesheet.getLastRow()-1;
  var workspacedata = workspacesheet.getRange(2,2,lastRows-1,1).getValues();
  var ciswsLocation = cisss.getSheetByName("HourlyUsed")

  for(var im = 0; im < lastRows; im++)  {      
    var encodedata = encodeURIComponent(workspacedata[im][0]);
    var cisurl = "https://testapi.com/v1/workspaceDurationMetrics?workspaceId="+encodedata+"&aggregation=daily&measurement=timeUsed&from="+thirtydate+"T00%3A00%3A00.00Z&to="+todaydate+"T00%3A00%3A00.00Z";
    var lastRow = ciswsLocation.getLastRow();

    var headers = {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${apikey} `
    };

    var options = {
        "method" : "get",
        "headers" : headers 
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(cisurl,options);
    var cisjson=response.getContentText();
    var cisdata=JSON.parse(cisjson);
       
    var results = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < cisdata['items'].length; i++) {
      let row = []
      row[0] = cisdata["workspaceId"];
      row[1] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(cisdata["items"][i]['start']), "UTC", "yyyy-MM-dd");
      row[2] = cisdata["items"][i]['duration'];
      results.push(row);
    }
    ciswsLocation.getRange(lastRow+1,1,results.length,results[0].length).setValues(results);      
  }
}
```

Comment: This script is functioning well but in the output sheet, I am only getting last device details.
Can you please confirm `var results = [];` is saving all the data in the for loop?
I think this is saving for's last loop data.

Comment: `row` contains the 3 values from `csidata` for each `i`.  Then the row is pushed making `results` a 2D array of `cisdata['items'].length`.  If not there may be something wrong with your data.

Comment: I moved `var lastRow = ciswsLocation.getLastRow();` inside the loop

Answer (score 1):

I will provide my particular approach to this problem, as I think it may be of interest to the community.

Since the OP has not provided the type of response the API provides (and refers that it is for private use), I will use a public API for the example, [Google Books APIs](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/reference/volumes/list) in this case. I will also consider that the calls are made to the same API, so the response is assumed to be identical.

I think the problem can be divided into 4 major steps.

1. Generate the URLs of the calls (depends on the API).
2. Get the data via [`UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(Object)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchAll(Object))
3. Normalize the data (this is the most critical step, as it depends on the API response). The main point is to obtain an array of arrays (`Object[][]`) as required for the next step.
4. Write the data to the sheet using [`setValues(Object[][])`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues).

Full example [here](https://script.google.com/d/1fmhQOFst_TK0AbZL1ZO9KtyB6WPdQiW0DSA9cusQ3EbWSg3eDA9UBkEA/edit?usp=sharing).

###### Generate URLs

```js
const generateUrl = (authors) => authors.map(author => `https://books.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${author}&country=US`)
```

###### Get The Data

```js
const fetchAndNormalizeData = (urlList) => {
  const resAll = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(urlList).map(res => res.getContentText())
  return resAll.map(normalizeResponse).flat()
}
```

##### Normalize The Data

```js
const normalizeResponse = (res) => {
  /* This depends on the RestAPI response */
  const { items } = JSON.parse(res)
  return items.map((book) => {
    const { selfLink, volumeInfo: { title, authors, publishedDate } } = book
    const parsedAuthors = authors ? authors.join('\n') : ""
    return [title, parsedAuthors, selfLink, publishedDate]
  })
}
```

###### Write to Sheet

```js
const writeToSheet = (data) => {
  sS
    .getRange(sS.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length)
    .setValues(data)
  console.log("DATA SAVED")
}
```

###### Main function

```js
const SS_ID = "<SS_ID>"
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SS_ID).getSheetByName('BookData')

const main = () => {
  const urlList = generateUrl(["Twain", "Joyce", "Pasternak"])
  const data = fetchAndNormalizeData(urlList)
  writeToSheet(data)
}
```

---

In the case of the OP just have to modify the `normalizeResponse` (callback for the map function) and `generateUrl` to adapt it to their needs.

###### Documentation:

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)